# how to call a method immediately before the start of a test run in minitest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I have the following scenario in testing a large, distributed system via end-to-end tests:

```
Class A < Minitest::Spec

  before do 
    # stuff

    setup_runtime_environment
  end

end

Class B < Class A

  before do 
    # stuff
  end

end

Class C < Class B

  before do 
    # stuff
  end

end
```

Some tests only inherit from `Class A` - it is the most general and includes things which are relevant to testing the entire system.

`Class B` is more specific - it includes things which are relevant to a large group of tests, but still needs to be setup by the `setup_runtime_environment` method in `Class A`

`Class C` is the most specific - it includes things which are relevant only to a small group of tests,  but still needs to be setup by the `setup_runtime_environment` method in `Class A`

The problem is that the runtime environment, for various test purposes, needs to be configured differently when running 'overall' tests vs. 'general' tests vs. 'specific' tests, and it needs to be configured **before** it is initialized.

So I could add the `setup_runtime_environment` method to the end of each before block.  But more ideal would be a way to run that method immediately before the specs are run.  A 'just_before' block.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

To clarify:

If I'm running an 'overall' spec - one that inherits only from `Class A`, the stack looks something like this, assuming 'A' is the before block in `Class A` and 's' is `setup_runtime_environment`:

```
A -> s -> running of specs
```

Likewise if I'm running a specific spec - one that inherits from `Class C`, the stack would look something like this:

```
A -> s -> B -> C -> running of specs
```

I want 's' to be called at the very end of any chain:

```
A -> s -> running of specs
```

or

```
A -> B -> s -> running of specs
```

or

```
A -> B -> C -> s -> running of specs
```

which is what I mean by 'just before' - as in just before the specs are run.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just before". AFAIK, the `before` block *is* run just before each test (like the `setup` method in `Minitest::Test`).

Comment: sorry, i realize it's a bit confusing. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limited because of the behavior of the spec DSL. If you want to really control when your setup code is run along with the inherited setup, you should use the test-style [`setup`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Test/LifecycleHooks.html#method-i-setup) and `super`.

```
Class A < Minitest::Spec

  def setup
    # do stuff
    setup_runtime_environment
  end

end

Class B < Class A

  def setup
    super
    # do stuff after setup_runtime_environment
  end

end

Class C < Class B

  def setup
    # do stuff before setup_runtime_environment
    super
  end

end
```

Comment: that sounds promising - and probably you know what you're talking about ;)  I'll check it tomorrow after I try it out.